# Init WebApplicationContext in unit test

Tags: spring

I have a utility method that I wanted to write a unit test for. Since this utility runs under a webapp, it is designed to get a Spring bean from the WebApplicationContext.(follow code is not under unit test)
action bean class

```
private IUnitBiz unitBiz;
public UnitBean()
{
    unitBiz = CommonUtils.getBean(IUnitBiz.class);
}
```

in CommonUtils.class

```
public static ApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext() {
        return FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanType) {
        return getWebApplicationContext().getBean(beanType);
    }
```

------------------in unit test----------------

In unit test it is return null, how can i init WebApplicationContext or getBean for my unit test?
when i new action bean, getBean method is return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/) could be a solution.

Example:

```
WebApplicationContext mockWebApplicationContext = EasyMock.createMock(WebApplicationContext.class);
MockServletContext mockServletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE,
                                    mockWebApplicationContext);

EasyMock.expect(mockWebApplicationContext.getServletContext()).andReturn(mockServletContext).anyTimes();
```

Comment: i want to get bean from this method

Answer (score 0):

You could make your test case extends org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests.

By extending this class, you can access an instance of the org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext, which can be used and passed along your utility methods...
Actually, I don't know if you're using but you should try spring-test, it's the best way to use Spring in JUnit tests and it's framework independent (it can be used with Wicket, JSF, etc.).

You should start by including the dependency below in your Maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```